# How can I run specific android app automatically by using Docker?

Tags: android, docker, automated-tests, docker-image

I'm trying to build a docker image can run specific android app automatically. Now, I'm using arc-welder to do that. But It just open arc-welder not open arc-welder include my specific android app. I still need to pull my apk to arc-welder by myself. Does anyone have a good solution?

I see this tutorial : https://hub.docker.com/r/thshaw/arc-welder/

```
FROM arc-welder:base

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/google-chrome" ]

#This is the app-id of ARC Welder that we installed 
CMD [ "--user-data-dir=/data", "--app-id=emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn" ]
```

I start by use these command

Step 1. ( build a new image )

```
docker build -t arc-welder:latest
```

Step 2. ( Start the ARC Welder container )

```
docker run -it \
    --net host \
    --cpuset-cpus 0 \
    --memory 512mb \ # max memory it can use
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \ # mount the X11 socket
    -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY \
    -v $HOME/Downloads:/root/Downloads \
    --device /dev/snd \ # so we have sound
    --name arcwelder \
    arc-welder:latest
```

But it just run arc-welder excluding the android app I selected.

Comment: The link that you added has answer. Use `CMD args` in the end of Dockerfile. Can you show you dockerfile?

Comment: i have added Dockerfile.    thanks for your response~

Comment: how do you start manually? just put that into `CMD`

Comment: I have commit your question , thanks you

Comment: Any answer? I need it too